# how to render multiple fusioncharts to single html page in django

Tags: python, django, fusioncharts

I want to make a dashboard web app, so I need to use multiple fusion charts for same html page. I have tried making a dictionary but that only shows one chart and not the other one.

please help me achieve this so that i an render 3-4 charts. or if it doesn't work this way let me know any alternative?

views.py

```
context={
    'all_count': all_count,
    'total_high': total_high,
    'total_medium': total_medium,
    'total_low': total_low
  }

  status = FusionCharts('doughnut2d', 'ex1', '600', '400', 'chart-1', 'json', """{
      "chart": {
        "showpercentvalues": "1",
        "aligncaptionwithcanvas": "0",
        "captionpadding": "0",
        "decimals": "1",
        "plottooltext": "<b>$percentValue</b> of offenses <b>$label</b>",
        "centerlabel": "# Users: $value",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "label": "Opened offense",
          "value": "1000"
        },
        {
          "label": "Closed offense",
          "value": "5300"
        }
      ]
  }""")

  context2 = {
        'monthly': monthly.render(),
        'status': status.render()
  }


    # returning complete JavaScript and HTML code, which is used to generate chart in the browsers.
  return  render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'context2': context2, 'context': context})
```

dashboard.html

```
<div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="card">
               <div id="chart-1">{{ context2.monthly|safe }}</div>

           </div>
      </div>
 </div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row m-t-25">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div id="chart-2">{{ context2.status|safe }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to create two FusionCharts constructor and pass unique div container's id to it

for example:
 status1 = FusionCharts('doughnut2d', 'ex1', '600', '400', 'chart-1', 'json', """
 status2 = FusionCharts('doughnut2d', 'ex1', '600', '400', 'chart-2', 'json', """

Comment: @Zapdos13 I have done it in the same way. I have created two FusionCharts constructors with different id 'chart-1' and 'chart-2'. Then I have used those id's to accordingly in the html template. `<div id="chart-2">{{context.status|safe}}</div>` and  `<div id="chart-1">{{ context.monthly|safe }}</div>`

Comment: I basically found the error, I had to change 'id' attribute to which was same for both not only renderAt so for the second constructor i change ex1 to ex2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way you can implement the drill-down functionality, you can create unlimited levels of drill-down with a single data source.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Include the `fusioncharts.py` file that contains functions to embed the charts.
from fusioncharts import FusionCharts

from ..models import *

# The `chart` function is defined to load data from a `Country` Model. 
# This data will be converted to JSON and the chart will be rendered.

def chart(request):
    # Chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter, as dict, in the form of key-value pairs.
    dataSource = {}
    dataSource['chart'] = { 
        "caption": "Top 10 Most Populous Countries",
        "showValues": "0",
        "theme": "zune"
        }

    # Convert the data in the `Country` model into a format that can be consumed by FusionCharts. 
    # The data for the chart should be in an array where in each element of the array is a JSON object
    # having the `label` and `value` as keys.

    dataSource['data'] = []
    dataSource['linkeddata'] = []
    # Iterate through the data in `Country` model and insert in to the `dataSource['data']` list.
    for key in Country.objects.all():
      data = {}
      data['label'] = key.Name
      data['value'] = key.Population
      # Create link for each country when a data plot is clicked.
      data['link'] = 'newchart-json-'+ key.Code
      dataSource['data'].append(data)

      # Create the linkData for cities drilldown    
      linkData = {}
      # Inititate the linkData for cities drilldown
      linkData['id'] = key.Code
      linkedchart = {}
      linkedchart['chart'] = {
        "caption" : "Top 10 Most Populous Cities - " + key.Name ,
        "showValues": "0",
        "theme": "zune"
        }

      # Convert the data in the `City` model into a format that can be consumed by FusionCharts.    
      linkedchart['data'] = []
      # Filtering the data base on the Country Code
      for key in City.objects.all().filter(CountryCode=key.Code):
        arrDara = {}
        arrDara['label'] = key.Name
        arrDara['value'] = key.Population
        linkedchart['data'].append(arrDara)

      linkData['linkedchart'] = linkedchart
      dataSource['linkeddata'].append(linkData)

    # Create an object for the Column 2D chart using the FusionCharts class constructor                 
    column2D = FusionCharts("column2D", "ex1" , "700", "400", "chart-1", "json", dataSource)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'output': column2D.render()})
```